# how to positon two contents left and right using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Am trying to align a logo and a menu (to the left and the other to the right), i used **class="pull-left"** for my logo and **class="pull-right"** for my menu icon (because i use bootstrap) but when applied this class attribute to this contents (which are inside a div tag) my menu icon always goes to the bottom. 
I will like to know why i do encounter this, and also how to fix this.

*below is an image of how i want my alignments to look like;*

[image]

Comment: maybe show us your code so we can actually fix it ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: float:left; float:right;

Comment: no need, i just figured a way with the help of this answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use css float property

```
float-left {
    float: left;
}

float-right {
    float: left;
}
```

or you can use flex-box too.

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...

    ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem.
    ...solicit opinions rather than facts." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer